# Name a group of frequently used items or things

Tags: meaning

What name would you give to a grouping of items or things that you use frequently? I am preferrably looking for a one word answer please.

Comment: Can you provide more context around what the "items or things" are?  Are they physical items or are they more like skills.  There are a lot of words you could you use in varying scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This might be too specific, but what about tool set?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, `essentials`.......

Comment: I've no idea why someone downvoted this, it seems the most appropriate answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

Favourites come to mind........................

Answer (score 0):

The french word ***nécessaire*** used as a noun might be what you're looking for.

Its widely used in Spanish too as "the group of things you always take with you". Also, some small handbags are called *nécessaires* because they are used to carry those items.

Comment: That would be necessities, but that does not necessarily match with things you frequently use. It might also be food or your toothbrush.